# SortedSetRangeByScoreWithScores issue with positive infinity values

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

When a Redis Sorted Set has an item with +Infinity score, trying to get its score returns `double.NaN` instead of `double.PositiveInfinity`.

This happen with both `SortedSetRangeByScoreWithScores` and `SortedSetRangeByRankWithScores` methods.

Note the last assert fails:

```
var cnn = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("...");
var db = cnn.GetDatabase();
db.SortedSetAdd("key", "first", double.NegativeInfinity);
db.SortedSetAdd("key", "last", double.PositiveInfinity);
var result = db.SortedSetRangeByScoreWithScores("key", double.NegativeInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);
Assert.AreEqual(double.NegativeInfinity, result[0].Score);
Assert.AreEqual(double.PositiveInfinity, result[1].Score);  // <-- This assert fails
```

[image: Locals]

This is the result via redis-cli:

[image]

Refers to StackExchange.Redis issue [#287](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/287)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that `double.PositiveInfinity` string value is `inf` on the Redis server but `+inf` on the client.

See this file:

> StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/Format.cs

lines

```
68: if (double.IsPositiveInfinity(value)) return "+inf";
147: if(string.Equals("+inf", s, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```

Try setting these strings to `"inf"` instead of `"+inf"` and run the updated client.

Comment: I was guessing the same but didn't find where it was defined. Thanks that helped!

Comment: @thepirat000 www.beyondgrep.com has ack, a great tool for search source code! I used that too.